# Cross-validating the tbats/bats function in forecast

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, tbats

Is there a way to cross validate the tbats/bats function in the forecast package in R? I have been trying to get CV weighted parameters which then I can pass to a function for revised estimates. However, have so far been unable to because the function calculates it automatically, but does not seem to accept predetermined parameters. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [time series cross-validation](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5), but as you note, there is not overly much you can do with the results, since `tbats()` does not allow you to explicitly set parameters. You can, of course, determine based on your cross-validation whether or not to use a Box-Cox transformation or a trend etc. The help page `?tbats` gives you a list of function parameters you can set.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, actually think I have figured it out. Believe we can look at the fitted values based on weights of the errors after cross-validation and that should be the CV'ed estimates...